# Google Play displaying my app version as Varies with device

Tags: android, google-play

I recently updated my app on Google Play Store. In my app page on play store it is displaying the version as **Varies with device**
I did not uploaded multiple apk and updated my app with the single apk. Then why it displaying the version as **Varies with device**

Is there any setting to remove this and show the actual version of App on Play Store.

Comment: Did you change minSdkVersion in the manifest?

Comment: @Patrick It is same as the previous version. I did not change the minSdkVersion.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You must **HAVE** uploaded another **APK** and put both your **PREVIOUS** and **CURRENT APK** into **PRODUCTION**. You are using **Multi APK support**.

Check your **Google Play Publisher** account, Click on the **Application**, Click **APK**. It should look something like this:

[image]

Reason: This happens because you did not **DEACTIVATE** your **PREVIOUS** APK first **BEFORE** adding the **LATEST** APK.

Read more here: http://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html